# C++ Initialize Class Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

Edit -- I updated the class code:

```
#include "MenuItem.h"
#include <string.h>

MenuItem::MenuItem(const char* txt, const int len)
{
    this->InitText(txt, len);
}

MenuItem::~MenuItem()
{
    delete[] Text;    
}

void MenuItem::InitText(const char* txt, const int len)
{
    Text = new char[len];
    strcpy(Text, txt);
}

void MenuItem::ResetText(const char* txt, const int len)
{
    if (len)
    {
        if (Text)
        {
            delete[] Text;           
        }
        Text = new char[len];
    }
    strcpy(Text, txt);
}
```

I am trying to implement an array of class objects, and the class
has no empty constructor. When I try to initialize the first element I get a segmentation fault.

To declare and set the array,

```
MenuItem **menuItems;
menuItems = (MenuItem**) malloc(sizeof (MenuItem) * 8);
```

In my main method I have:

```
#include "MainApp.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace Main_App;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MenuItem **menuItems;
    const char title[] = "         Main Title Here                ";
    const char menu1[] = "  1)  Item One                          ";
    const char menu2[] = "  2)  Item Two                          ";
    const char menu3[] = "  3)  Item Three                        ";
    const char menu4[] = "  4)  Item Four                         ";
    const char menu5[] = "  5)  Help                              ";
    const char menu6[] = "  6)  Exit                              ";

    menuItems = (MenuItem**) malloc(sizeof (MenuItem) * 8);


    *menuItems[0] = MenuItem(title, 40); /*<== segmentation fault occurs here */
    *menuItems[1] = MenuItem(menu1, 40);
    *menuItems[2] = MenuItem(menu2, 40);
    *menuItems[3] = MenuItem(menu3, 40);
    *menuItems[4] = MenuItem(menu4, 40);
    *menuItems[5] = MenuItem(menu5, 40);
    *menuItems[6] = MenuItem(menu6, 40);
    *menuItems[7] = MenuItem("", 40);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        puts(menuItems[i]->Text);
    }

    printf("At main(). Menu App exiting.\n");
    return 0;

}
```

The class:

```
#ifndef MENUITEM_H
#define MENUITEM_H

#include "malloc.h"
class MenuItem {
public:
    MenuItem(const char* txt, const int len);
    ~MenuItem();
    void ResetText(const char* txt, const int len = 0);     
    char *Text;
private:
    void InitText (const char* txt, const int len);
};

#endif /* MENUITEM_H */

/**  MenuItem.cpp file */
#include "MenuItem.h"
#include <string.h>

MenuItem::MenuItem(const char* txt, const int len) {
    this->InitText(txt, len);
}

MenuItem::~MenuItem() {
    if (Text) {
        free(Text);
    }
}

void MenuItem::InitText(const char* txt, const int len) {
    Text = (char*) malloc(len);
    strcpy(Text, txt);
}

void MenuItem::ResetText(const char* txt, const int len) {
    if (len) {
        if (Text) {
            free(Text);            
        }
        Text = (char*) malloc(len);
    }
    strcpy(Text, txt);
}
```

I can modify the class and add an empty constructor, but I would prefer to not do this, to ensure a C-string is always used in the initialization.

This is compiled in Linux 32-bit g++.

-Matt

Comment: C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Why are you using `char[]` variables?

Comment: Don't mix C and C++.  In C++ use `std::sting` and `std::vector` instead of trying to do the allocations yourself.

Comment: To clarify krpra's comment, do not tag C when your question is about C++ and vice-versa.  The answers you will get will be different depending on the language.

Comment: `(MenuItem**) malloc(sizeof (MenuItem) * 8);` `->` `(MenuItem**) malloc(sizeof (MenuItem*) * 8);`

Comment: `malloc`ing objects is a really bad idea. You get storage, but you do not get construction. You might get away with it because you have a really simple class, but you can't count on `Text` being `NULL`, so the destructor... probably gonna die.

Comment: Also you are violating the heck out of [the Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Thanks. I will change malloc to new and delete.

Comment: Neither of these work:      menuItems = (MenuItem**) malloc(sizeof (MenuItem*) * 8); 
    menuItems = (MenuItem**) malloc(1024 * 8);

Comment: @Mattz If you're going to use `new[]` to create a string, create a string class if you want to really learn how to do these things without using `std::string`.  If you're going to use `new[]` to create a dynamic array, create a dynamic array class if you want to know how `vector` does this.   Otherwise you're going to fall into the trap of writing spaghetti-like logic trying to pair `new` and `delete` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title literal `"         Main Title Here                "` is of length `41`, i.e. `40` characters + string termination character, but you reserve only 40 bytes. So you are one off and should reserve 41 bytes.

Try:

```
int main() {
    char l[] = "         Main Title Here                ";
    printf("%ld",sizeof(l));
}
```

Output:

```
41
```

Another issue is that you declare `menuItems` as being of type pointer to pointer to `MenuItem`. Then, with `*menuItem[0]`, you dereference a pointer that is not initialized and therefore points to an invalid object. That's the root cause for the seg fault.

You could either declare `menuItem` as an array of `MenuItem`s, but then `MenuItem` would require a default constructor. Another option would be to keep the "pointer to pointer"-metaphor and assign pointers to objects created with `new`:

```
menuItems = (MenuItem**) malloc(sizeof (MenuItem*) * 8);

menuItems[0] = new MenuItem(title, 40);
menuItems[1] = new MenuItem(menu1, 40);
menuItems[2] = new MenuItem(menu2, 40);
menuItems[3] = new MenuItem(menu3, 40);
menuItems[4] = new MenuItem(menu4, 40);
menuItems[5] = new MenuItem(menu5, 40);
menuItems[6] = new MenuItem(menu6, 40);
menuItems[7] = new MenuItem("", 40);
```

Anyway, you mix C-style with C++. I'd suggest to dive into the world of C++ and use `std::vector`, `new`, `delete`, ... and get rid of `malloc` and `free`.
Also think of using `std::string`; a lot of issues coming from "small" mistakes in memory management will simply not arise...

Comment: Shortened each Char array, same problem.

Comment: This is for an embedded device where the processor's frequency is about 400Mhz, and the dynamic RAM is limited to 32 MB. I would prefer to stick with C-strings, but I am open to the idea of vectors and using std::string.